# How do I prove that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ converges without applying the series integral test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am at a loss as to how I can prove that the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\:\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ converges. At first I tried the ratio test, but that came out inconclusive. Then I tried it by showing that the sequence of partial sums is bounded, to no avail. If anyone could give me a hint on this, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I almost forgot to mention: I need a prove specifically without applying the series integral test, because this is not covered in my maths course and proves should only be done with the material available from the course.

Comment: Try LCT with $a_n=\ln\Big(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: Use [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615890?seq=1) inequality
$$\frac{x}{1+x}\leq \ln(1+x)\leq x, \forall x > -1$$
and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) result.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2736836 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1920755

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $0 \le \ln(1+n^{-2}) \le n^{-2}$ for all integers $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}n^2\ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2})=1$$

So, for $ n $ great enough
$$n^2\ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2})\le 2$$

or

$$\ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2})\le \frac{2}{n^2}$$

Conclude by comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Mean value theorem:

$\log (1+1/n^2)=$

$\dfrac{\log (1+n^2)-\log (n^2)}{1}= \dfrac{1}{c}\le \dfrac{1}{n^2},$ where $c \in [n^2,n^2+1].$

Answer (score 0):

*Since you have been given the answers for the comparison test ...*

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\log\left(\prod _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right)=\log \left(\frac{\sinh (\pi )}{\pi }\right)$$